# Convert .tar.gz/.tar.bz2 to .7z in batch?

Tags: windows, conversion, tar, 7-zip, gz

How do I convert .tar.gz and .tar.bz2 files to .7z files using the command line?

Comment: You might be able to edit [this script converting from zip](http://www.howtogeek.com/50893/easily-convert-all-your-zip-archives-to-7z-archives/) to fit your demands? Also there is [an online converter](http://www.zamzar.com/) supporting the mentioned formats.

Comment: @N.N.: Thanks for the link... it seems to be what I want, aside from the fact that it requires a temporary directory (which is nontrivial, given that my files are big). I'll give it a try anyhow; thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't avoid writing the files to disk in an uncompressed form. I don't think any useful compression algorithm can do its work without having the whole file to look at.

Comment: Would the biggest of your files fit into memory uncompressed?  If so, you might find it worthwhile to use a ramdisk for the temporary files?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I missed the '`windows`' tag on your question completely.
So, unless you use some unix tools (Cygwin?), this answer is not usable there.
I am expecting `cygwin` to implement this pipe correctly -- you'll need `bash`, `tar`, `bzip2` and `7z` from the environment.

---

You can pipe the tar output into a 7z like this,

```
tar xfj filename.tar.bz2 | 7z a -si filename.7z
```

and similarly,

```
tar xfz filename.tar.gz | 7z a -si filename.7z
```

This will save you the disk-space for extracted data -- but its not converting inline.
You will still need sufficient space to store the '`7z`' being created from the tarball.
You can only delete the tarball after the pipe ends.

Comment: `tar xf file.tar` extracts files to disk , perhaps you meant to say `tar -xf file.tar -O` which sends the extracted files to StdOut

Comment: I submitted an edit to resolve the above issue (extracting to disk rather than stdout), but alas this still does not work - it compresses the tar archive as a single file within the 7z, rather than creating a 7z of the files within the tar

Answer (score 0):

try [ArcConvert](http://archivconvert.sourceforge.net/).

i did not personally tested this program but it says it does what you want , from their site :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This convertor can convert the following archives:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7-ZIP/ LZH / CAB / ZIP / ARJ / ACE / RAR / TAR / TGZ / GZ / Z / BZ2 / YZ1 /
YZ2 / GCA / BEL / RPM / DEB/ BH / Noa32 / HKI / PAQAR / SQX /HA /ZOO /
UHARC /LFB / ZLIB / UCL / IMP / RS / SPL / APK / Arc / DZ / MSI / ALZ /
PMA / PAQ7 / CHM / UDA / PAQ8 / Cryptonite / ISO / LZOP / BMA /
ZIP AES (128/192/256) / Nanozip Alpha/ XZ/ FreeArc/Zpaq/GZA
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
to the following ones:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZIP, 7-ZIP, CAB, LHA, TAR, TGZ, BZ2, YZ1, BGA, RAR, ACE, NOA32, PAQAR,
UHARC, YZ2, DZ, HA, XZ, FreeArc, ARJ/PAQ9/GZA
```

screenshot:

[image: ArcConvert]

Comment: The OP asked for a command line solution. Also, ArcConvert is just a GUI for various tools. Internally it uses for example `7z.exe` which is a command line tool.